# invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'std::basic_ostream<char>::char_type {aka char}'

Tags: c++

Can't get around this problem

```
ofstream out;
out.open("o");
string a[5][5];
//fill array with letters from 'in.get(ch)'...and then i've tryed:
//1
out.put(a[row[0]][col[1]].c_str()); //=>invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'std::basic_ostream<char>::char_type {aka char}'
//2:
out.put(const_cast<char *>(a[row[0]][col[1]].c_str())); //=>invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'std::basic_ostream<char>::char_type {aka char}' 
//3
char x=const_cast<char *>(a[row[0]][col[1]].c_str());
out.put(x); //=>invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char'
```

Nothin seems to be working. Can you help me? What should i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ofstream::put()` is for putting individual characters, not strings, to the stream.

If you want to print the string to the file stream, why not simply use `<<`:

out << a[row[0]][col[1]];